# Set max number for checkboxes that can be selected for a form in Element-ui?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to set the checkboxes from an array with a `v-for` currently I'm saving the number the user inputs for the amount of checkboxes that can be selected, how can I correctly merge setting the checkboxes with a `v-if` and setting the `"min: '1' :max:'form.num'`.

Right now I'm showing all the checkboxes in the array but the min max don't work? If I try another way the checkboxes don't show up at all.

What shows the checkboxes but min max doesn't work

```
<el-form-item :min="1" :max="form.num" v-for="(option, index) in questionOptions" 
        :key="index">
    <el-checkbox :label="option.option"></el-checkbox>
</el-form-item>
```

This is like the docs but the checkboxes don't show up at all, and I get this error multiple times

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" found in
<ElCheckbox>

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at VueComponent.isLimitDisabled
```

```
<el-form-item>
    <el-checkbox-group :min="1" :max="form.num">
        <el-checkbox v-for="(option, index) in questionOptions" :key="index">
            {{option.option}}
        </el-checkbox>
    </el-checkbox-group>
</el-form-item>
```

Where is my mistake? or How am I supposed to do it correctly?

Comment: I looked the docs for [min/max](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/checkbox#minimum-maximum-items-checked) and I don't see that you have `v-model` on your `<el-checkbox-group>`...

Comment: For `undefined` error, make sure that `questionOptions` default value is `[]`

Comment: @ljubadr as far as I understood that it's for the check items that you want, I don't want any selected at the beginning

Comment: @ljubadr for the `questionOptions` it can't be `[]` because those options have already been saved, I want to display them as checkboxes

Comment: You need the `v-model`, even if it's an empty `[]` array. I just tested in `element-ui` [codepen for min/max](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true). Without `v-model` it shows error in the console `Error in render: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'`

Comment: Error `Error in render: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'` is also related to missing `v-model`

Comment: @ljubadr I added an empty `v-model` but it's still not working correctly, even if the max is 3 I can only click on one before they all disable?

Comment: That's is weird... Can you edit this [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true) with what you have right now and share back the link when you finish editing? Also, if you are not already using browser extension [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) I recommend installing it :)

Comment: @ljubadr the codepen is empty

Comment: My mistake, try [this one](https://codepen.io/ljubadr/pen/oNNLaEY?&editable=true) I used basic example from `element-ui`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200974/discussion-between-nancy-and-ljubadr).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it

```
<template>
   <el-checkbox-group :min="1" :max="max" v-model='optionsSelected'>
    <el-checkbox v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
        {{option}}
    </el-checkbox>
  </el-checkbox-group>
</template>
<script>
     data() {
  return {
    optionsSelected: ['lalala','lololo'],
    options: [],
    max:3,
  },
 async created(){

      const options = await axios.get('your endpoint');
      this.options = options.data;

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me I'm getting the array of options from the database

Comment: is the same you just fill optios from database, 
let me edit the answer to fill from db.